# Removing div element where style="background-"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Curious one. I want to remove a div element when `background-image: url('')`

I've tried the following:

```
$('.bg-image-card').each(function(){
  if ($(this).css('background-image', "url('')") ){
    $(this).remove();
  };
});
```

It works - but removes all divs with background images or not. The reason why I am using it is just to remove those where url('') - any pointers would be great!

i.e.,

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `getElementsByTagName("div")` then loop over them looking for the lowercased and trimmed string. To remove, either simply classList.add("hidden") or search for how to delete self function via ParentElement.

Comment: `jQuery(".bg-image-card[style*='background-image: url(\\'\\');']")` seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.css()` does not return a `Boolean` value; `.css()` returns a jQuery object which will evaluate "truthy".

When an empty string is passed to CSS `url()` function the value within `url()` is replaced with `location.href`, which appears to be a bug which am able to reproduce at both Chromium and Firefox

> [**3.4.2. Empty URLs**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#url-empty)
>
> If the value of the url() is the empty string (like url("") or url()), the url must resolve to an invalid resource
>   (similar to what the url about:invalid does).

```js
$("div").each(function() {   
  if (window.getComputedStyle(this).backgroundImage === `url("${location.href}")`) {
    $(this).remove()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-image:url('')">div</div>
<div>div</div>
```

Bug reports [Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=804170), [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1432049)

Comment: Whack - and it works first time. I guess you either know this or you don't! :)

Comment: @guest271314 , is var s = `${ location.href }` ES6 ? i am a bit confused :|

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik See [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Oh yes thanks , i had forgotten what they call them ! :| Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong with my assumption.

<strike>You can use:</strike>

```
$('.bg-image-card').each(function(){
  if ($(this).css('background-image') == "url('')" ){
    $(this).remove();
  };
});
```

However, you can check background image width or height and remove it if it's width or height is 0:

```
$('.bg-image-card').each(function(){
  var bg = new Image();
  bg.src = $(this).css('background-image').replace(/"/g,"").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");
  if(bg.width == 0) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```